# Error when create List in Orchard CMS 1.10.1

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.10

comrades! I have some trouble with create list in Orchard CMS follow  http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Creating-lists/
I get source code from github and run from VS. Then I create new Content Type - Book Review and set him Containeble part. Then I enabled List module, and go to create list page from side bar admin panel and create Book Review List with reference to Book Review  Content Type. Then I try to create Book Review, and when I click save I see exception message ([exception image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmOyF.png)). If i disable List module then exception is gone, but i cant crete list. What is this error? How can I avoid it? Or how can I create list in Orcahrd?

Comment: Add your exception too in your question.What exception you getting?

Comment: @Hina Khuman, I added link to image exception in question